# How to Receive first 100 mail Messages in using Imap Client In C#

Tags: c#, imap

I have an account on Gmail with 12,000 mail messages in inbox mailbox folder.
My problem is that I want to receive only top 100 mail messages, I tried a lot but I failed. 
Here's the code

```
ImapClient go_client = new ImapClient();

CompletionResponse go_response = null;

Mailbox go_Folders_As_Tree = null;

go_client.Host = "Host";
go_client.Port = "port no";
go_client.Username = "user id";
go_client.Password = "pasword";

go_client.SSLInteractionType = EInteractionType.SSLPort;
go_response = go_client.Login();

go_Folders_As_Tree = go_client.GetMailboxTree();

Mailbox inbox = Mailbox.Find(go_Folders_As_Tree, "INBOX");

MessageCollection tmp = go_client.GetAllMessageHeaders(inbox);

foreach (ImapMessage msg in tmp)
        {
            ImapMessage actual_message = go_client.GetMessageText(msg.UID,      go_Folders_As_Tree.Children[1]);
        }
```

This way I have to wait for all my 12,000 mail messages.

Answer (score 0):

```
int maxCount = 200;

for (int i = 1; i <= maxCount; i++) {
// Your Code here...
}
```

Comment: but we have to provide UID for each message how can i get the UID of first message

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good time to use LINQ's [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) extension method:

```
MessageCollection tmp = go_client.GetAllMessageHeaders(inbox);

foreach (ImapMessage msg in tmp.Take(100))
{
    ImapMessage actual_message = go_client.GetMessageText(msg.UID,      go_Folders_As_Tree.Children[1]);
}
```

Note that this still downloads all 12,000 headers, but only the content of the first 100 (if this is a problem, give us a link to your `ImapClient` documentation so we might be able to find a better approach). Also note that if the headers are unordered, you'll get an unpredictable set of emails, and you might want to do an `OrderBy` first. (e.g. `tmp.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Date).Take(100)`)

Comment: if we use GetMessageHeader Method instead of GetAllMessageHeaders and we have to provide start UID and end UID But problem is that how can we get the UID of First mail Message

Comment: Have you tried it as I have it? Is the time acceptable? If so, great you're done. If not: what IMAP library are you using? I'd like to see the documentation and/or try it myself.

Comment: i am using Email.net library but there's not fuction for getting the UID of first message.